# Ignore if cell is blank

Tags: excel

I am currently using this formula to ignore the cell if it is blank.

=IF([@X<>"",1,0)

However, the problem is that if someone inputs "0" instead of just leaving it blank, my formula is not going to work anymore because the new output will be 1 and not 0. If the cell is 6 (or any value greater than 0), my desired output will be 1.

How can I fix it?

Comment: `=IF([@X]="","",MIN([@X],1))`?

Comment: You rock Scott! Thanks a lot

Comment: If the options are just empty or anything above zero,  then maybe just `=IF([@X]>1,1,[@X])`